# How to pass variables as parameters with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Currently writing some code and I want to use `DateTime.Parse`, passing a string specifying the format, but with some variables as well.

Examples:

```
DateTime first_day = DateTime.Parse("{0}/01/{1}", Today.Month - 1, Today.Year - 1); 
DateTime first_day = DateTime.Parse("12/01/{0}", Today.Year - 1);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what the goal of this code is.

Comment: I would use the DateTime constructor that takes integer year, month, and day as parameters. Or `Today.AddMonth(-1).AddYear(-1)`. Unless there are some very special requirements here, there's probably no need to get strings and parsing involved.

Comment: Be very careful with `Month - 1`.  You'll end up trying to create dates that don't exist, such as June 31st.  `Year - 1` is even more dangerous, leading to creation of February 29th of a common year when run during a leap year.  Either will throw exceptions with both `DateTime.Parse` or `new DateTime`.  Instead, use the `AddMonth` and `AddYear` methods, as Ed mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use either string interpolation or manipulate variables passed to the constructor.  Either will have the consequence of trying to created dates that do not exist.

For example, when today is July 31st, trying to create a date of June 31st will throw an `FormatException` when using `DateTime.Parse`, or an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when using the `DateTime` constructor.

Likewise, trying to create a date of February 29th will only work when the associated year is a leap year.  `2020-02-29` is valid, but `2019-02-29` is not.

Also, passing a date in January such as `2020-01-01` would try to create a date in month 0 (`2019-00-01`), which is also invalid.

Instead, use the `AddYears` and/or `AddMonths` methods:

```
DateTime first_day = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-1); 
DateTime second_day = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
```

These will correctly move back to a valid date.  `July 31st - 1 month` becomes `June 30th`.  `Feb 29th 2020 - 1 year` becomes `Feb 28th 2019`, etc.

If you need to snap to the first of the month, then you could do something like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-1);
DateTime first_day = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
```

(All months have a day 1.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) (came with [C# 6.0 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation)) like;

```
DateTime first_day = DateTime.Parse($"{Today.Month - 1}/01/{Today.Year - 1}");
```

and

```
DateTime first_day = DateTime.Parse($"12/01/{Today.Year - 1}");
```

without any parameter needs in your `DateTime.Parse` methods. This method does *not* support [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting), so what you do is not possible.

You can use [`new DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) constructor also as Ed [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56840615/how-to-pass-variables-as-parameters-with-datetime#comment100233543_56840615) which takes year, month and day as a parameter.

By the way, as Matt mentioned, these Month-1 calculations is an anti pattern they can lead you to some dates that doesn't exists. [See his answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56840934/447156).

Comment: @Boballendo You are probably using a lower verison of C# 6.0. That's okay. Instead of that, you can use `new DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor as well as I mentioned at the end. Other option might be using `string.Format` in your `DateTime.Parse` method but that's seems like an overkill.

Comment: This only works when parsed with a format provider that uses month/day/year ordering, and when the day is 01 as shown here.  If the day isn't fixed to 01, then it could throw a `FormatException` when passed an invalid date.

Comment: Actually, I also missed that month-1 doesn't work in January.  (There's no month 0).  So still not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.Format` like that:

```
var first_day = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/01/{1}", DateTime.Today.Month - 1, DateTime.Today.Year - 1));
```